# How to properly write R-Value overloads for operators

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, move-semantics

For context, the actual class I'm working with is considerably more complicated and larger than what I'm showing here, but I'm using this just as an example.

```
struct Vector {
    int x, y;
    Vector() : Vector(0,0) {}
    Vector(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

I'd like to add operator overloads to allow `Vector`s to be added and subtracted from each other.

```
Vector& operator+=(Vector const& v) {
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    return *this;
}
Vector operator+(Vector const& v) const {
    return Vector(*this) += v;
}
Vector& operator-=(Vector const& v) {
    x -= v.x;
    y -= v.y;
    return *this;
}
Vector operator-(Vector const& v) const {
    return Vector(*this) -= v;
}
```

However, This code can allow unfortunate constructions:

```
int main() {
    Vector & a = Vector(1,2) += Vector(5,4);//This compiles and invokes undefined behavior!
    std::cout << a.x << ',' << a.y << std::endl;//This isn't safe!
}
```

So I rewrote the code to be mindful of whether the object is an L-value or R-value:

```
Vector& operator+=(Vector const& v) & {
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    return *this;
}
Vector&& operator+=(Vector const& v) && {
    return std::move(*this += v);
}
Vector operator+(Vector const& v) const {
    return Vector(*this) += v;
}
Vector& operator-=(Vector const& v) & {
    x -= v.x;
    y -= v.y;
    return *this;
}
Vector&& operator-=(Vector const& v) && {
    return std::move(*this -= v);
}
Vector operator-(Vector const& v) const {
    return Vector(*this) -= v;
}
```

So my remaining question is, even though this code compiles and does what I'm *expecting*, is this code safe and free of unexpected Undefined Behavior?

```
int main() {
    //No Longer compiles, good.
    //Vector & a = Vector(1,2) += Vector(5,4);

    //Is this safe?
    Vector b = Vector(1,2) += Vector(5,4);

    //Other cases where this code could be unsafe?
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you should just disallow compound assignment on rvalues altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever need to += with an rvalue. I think this is an interesting question, but the use cases seem a bit silly to me. I would probably just make this use case invalid. Especially in this case since Vectors are very straightforward value types that you generally won't be allocating on the heap all that often. Heck, they don't even really need destructors or move semantics since they're just 2 ints (or floats) glued together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are relatively standard ways to overload these operators:

```
Vector& operator+=(Vector const& v)& {
  x += v.x;
  y += v.y;
  return *this;
}
friend Vector operator+(Vector lhs, Vector const& v) {
  lhs+=v;
  return std::move(lhs); // move is redundant yet harmless in this case
}
Vector& operator-=(Vector const& v)& {
  x -= v.x;
  y -= v.y;
  return *this;
}
friend Vector operator-(Vector lhs, Vector const& v) {
  lhs -= v;
  return std::move(lhs); // move is redundant yet harmless in this case
}
```

note that on a line of many `+` or `-`, the above generates way fewer copies and more moves than your overloads do.

`a+b+c` becomes `(a+b)+c`, and the return value of `a+b` is elided directly into the lhs argument of `+c`.  And the first line of your `+` consisted of creating a copy anyhow, so the extra copy in the signature is harmless.

Unless you have a great reason why, ban `+=` and `=` on rvalues.  `int` doesn't support it, you shouldn't either.

Comment: Why `std::move(lhs)` and not `return lhs;` in `friend Vector operator+/-`? Doesn't the first disable RVO?

Comment: @vsoftco no elision for returning function arguments is permitted.  The move is still redundant, just not harmful here.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, do as int do.

Can you do compound assignment on `int` rvalues? Of course not. So why bother with your `Vector`?

---

Your `b` is safe, but `Vector&& c = Vector(1,2) += Vector(5,4);` isn't. The usual fix is to return by value, but returning by value from an assignment operator is also somewhat weird.

Answer (score 0):

Moving itself is bad idea.

```
Vector&& operator-=(Vector const& v) && {
    return std::move(*this -= v);
}
```

You can easily end up with a moved-from object without expecting that.

---

In the main:

```
int main() {
    Vector & a = Vector(1,2) += Vector(5,4);//This compiles and invokes undefined behavior!
    std::cout << a.x << ',' << a.y << std::endl;//This isn't safe!
}
```

Why don't just use

```
Vector a = Vector(1,2) + Vector(5,4)
```

---

As for properly using r-value references in operator overloads, you can use them only in the +, not in the +=. See the std::string [operator+](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) and [operator +=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D)